# Drawing an HSV color wheel in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, colors

So I am trying to create a simple color wheel in Qt C++ using `QPainter` and `QQuickPaintedItem`, however I can't seem to figure what I am doing wrong. I subclassed a `QQuickPaintedItem` and then in the `QQuickPaintedItem::paint` function I wrote a simple function like below.

```
#ifndef COLORWHEEL_H
#define COLORWHEEL_H

#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QtMath>

class ColorWheel : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
public:
    ColorWheel()
    {
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter) override
    {
        QPen pen;
        pen.setWidth(1);
        for(int w = 0; w <= width(); w++){

            for(int h = 0; h <= height(); h++){

                // coordinate transformation so that the origin is at the centre of the item
                // also y values should increase as you go up and decrease as you go down
                int a = w - width()/2;
                int b = height()/2 - h;

                Polar p = cartesianToPolar(a, b);


                // only paint pixels inside the circle
                if(p.radius <= width()/2){
                    qreal hue = p.angle/(2*M_PI) ;
                    qreal sat = p.radius/width()/2;

                    QColor color;
                    color.setHsvF(hue, sat, 1.0);
                    pen.setColor(color);

                    painter->setPen(pen);
                    painter->drawPoint(QPoint(w,h));
                }
            }
        }
    }
private:
    struct Polar{
        qreal radius;
        qreal angle;
    };

    Polar cartesianToPolar(qreal x, qreal y)
    {
        qreal theta = qAtan(y/x);

        if(theta < 0){
            theta += (2* M_PI);
        }
        qreal r = qSqrt((x*x) + (y*y));
        Polar p;
        p.angle = theta;
        p.radius = r;

        return p;
    }
};

#endif // COLORWHEEL_H
```

Then using `qmlRegisterType<ColorWheel>("Color", 1, 0, "ColorWheel");` I simply wrote a simple qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Color 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ColorWheel {
        width: 720
        height: 720
    }
}
```

This doesn't work as expected (the colors in the wheel are incorrect).

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720719/how-to-create-a-color-circle-in-pyqt/50723021) but it involves PyQt (I suppose the logic should be the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. The issue was mathematical as didn't remember that one cannot infer the quadrant of an angle simply by its tangent. Instead one should you use the `atan2` function which always return a positive angle when transforming cartesian coordinates.