# PyQt creating color circle

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to add a color circle to the widget placeholder there:
[image]

I already tried this library:
https://gist.github.com/tobi08151405/7b0a8151c9df1a41a87c1559dac1243a

But if the window wasnt a quadrat, the color circle didnt worked.
I have already tried the other solution, but there is no method to get the color value.
[How to create a "Color Circle" in PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720719/how-to-create-a-color-circle-in-pyqt)

Could you recommend/ show me a way of creating my own, so I can add them there?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget assumes that its shape is always a square; the code provides a custom `AspectLayout` for that, but it's not necessary.

The problem comes from the fact that when the shape is not a square the computation of the color is wrong, as coordinates are not properly mapped when a dimension is much bigger than the other. For instance, if the widget is much wider than tall, the x coordinate is "shifted" since the circle (which is now an actual ellipse) is shown centered, but the color function uses the *minimum* size.

The solution is to create an internal `QRect` that is always displayed at the center and use that for both painting *and* computation:

```py
class ColorCircle(QWidget):
    # ...
    def resizeEvent(self, ev: QResizeEvent) -> None:
        size = min(self.width(), self.height())
        self.radius = size / 2
        self.square = QRect(0, 0, size, size)
        self.square.moveCenter(self.rect().center())

    def paintEvent(self, ev: QPaintEvent) -> None:
        # ...
        p.setPen(Qt.transparent)
        p.setBrush(hsv_grad)
        p.drawEllipse(self.square)
        p.setBrush(val_grad)
        p.drawEllipse(self.square)
        # ...

    def map_color(self, x: int, y: int) -> QColor:
        x -= self.square.x()
        y -= self.square.y()
        # ...
```

Note that the code uses numpy, but it's used for functions that do not really require such a *huge* library for an application that clearly doesn't need numpy's performance.

For instance, the `line_circle_inter` uses a complex way to compute the position for the "cursor" (the small circle), but that's absolutely unnecessary, as the Hue and Saturation values already provide "usable" coordinates: the Hue indicates the angle in the circle (starting from 12 hour position, counter-clockwise), while the Saturation is the distance from the center.
QLineF provides a convenience function, [`fromPolar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinef.html#fromPolar), which returns a line with a given length and angle: the length will be the radius multiplied by the Saturation, the angle is the Hue multiplied by 360 (plus 90°, as angles start always at 3 o'clock); then we can translate that line at the center of the circle and the cursor will be positioned at the second point of the segment:

```py
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # ...
        p.setPen(Qt.black)
        p.setBrush(self.selected_color)
        line = QLineF.fromPolar(self.radius * self.s, 360 * self.h + 90)
        line.translate(self.square.center())
        p.drawEllipse(line.p2(), 10, 10)
```

The map color function can use the same logic, but inverted: we construct a line starting from the center to the mouse cursor position, then the Saturation is the length divided by the radius (sanitizing the value to `1.0`, as that's the maximum possible value), while the Hue is the line angle (minus 90° as above) divided by 360 and sanitized for a positive `0.0`-`1.0` range.

```py
    def map_color(self, x: int, y: int) -> QColor:
        line = QLineF(QPointF(self.rect().center()), QPointF(x, y))
        s = min(1.0, line.length() / self.radius)
        h = (line.angle() - 90) / 360 % 1.
        return h, s, self.v
```